# Always show min and max of colorbar in a Plotly.js heatmap

Tags: javascript, plotly, heatmap, plotly.js

In this example:

```js
const z = Array.from({length: 50}, () => Array.from({length: 50}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 47.2)));
Plotly.newPlot('plot',  [{z: z, type: 'heatmap'}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.26.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

the colorbar doesn't show precisely the min / max values. Here we only see `100`, `200`, ..., `500`, and we don't see the min value which is close to `47.2`, depending on the random sample.

**How to display the min / max values in the colorbar, with Plotly?**

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the [`colorbar`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/heatmap/#heatmap-colorbar) in the trace data directly.

Basically you want to specify the [`tickvals`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/heatmap/#heatmap-colorbar-tickvals), which implies that you set [`tickmode`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/heatmap/#heatmap-colorbar-tickmode) accordingly, eg. something like :

```js
const z = Array.from({length: 50}, () => Array.from({length: 50}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 47.2)));

// Computed from z.flat() : [zmin, ...someRange, zmax]
const tickvals = [47, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 547]

const data =  [{
  z: z, 
  type: 'heatmap',
  colorbar: {
    tickmode: 'array',
    tickvals
  }
}];

Plotly.newPlot('plot', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.26.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @EricLavault! Do you see a way to automatically have the min and max, and the best tickvals? Example: the min is 99 and max is 402, then [99, 100, 200, 300, 400, 402] won't be optimal for readability because 99 and 100 will be on top of each other.  Maybe there is a built-in optimized way to display the tickvals?

Comment: For the min/max you can do `zmin = Math.min(...z.flat())`, but afaik there is no way to make the `tickmode="auto"` behavior include zmin/zmax. Specifying tickvals implies we compute them beforehand, specifically the range in between zmin and zmax. In the example the range step or `dtick` is 100, this is the first thing to compute and it depends on the order of magnitude of `zmax - zmin` and the max number of ticks you want to be displayed; the range start or tick0 (100) is the first step after zmin, you might exclude it if `tick0 - zmin` is less than some threshold relative to dtick...

Comment: tick0, dtick, etc. this is the plotly vocabulary I'm using., you can refer to the documentation to get the proper meaning.